# Multiple Components from Same Lazy Route Not Working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Question - can I have multiple routes point to the same lazy loaded module (and associated router?).  I keep getting "Error: Cannot match any routes: 'Page30'".

Here is my app.routing.ts that sets up the lazy loading:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: Page1Component },                          // <-- default page
  { path: 'Page1', component: Page1Component },
  { path: 'Page2', component: Page2Component },
  { path: 'Page3', component: Page3Component },
  { path: 'Page30', loadChildren: './+lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' },
  { path: 'Page31', loadChildren: './+lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' },

  // { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }           // <-- route not found
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Here is the +lazy/lazy.routing.ts:

```
import { Page30Component } from './page30/page30.component';
import { Page31Component } from './page31/page31.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: Page30Component },
  {path: 'Page30', component: Page30Component},
  {path: 'Page31', component: Page31Component}

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders =   RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Here are the associated routerLinks.  (P1 is eager, 30 & 31 are lazy):

```
{ label: 'Take Payment', icon: 'ui-icon-assignment-ind', routerLink: ['/Page1'] },
{ label: 'Loss Mitigation', icon: 'ui-icon-announcement', routerLink: ['/Page31'] },
{ label: 'Bankruptcy', icon: 'ui-icon-create', routerLink: ['/Page30'] }
```

If I remove the '' default path in the lazy routing, I get the "Error: Cannot match any routes: 'Page30'".  The routeLinks look right as they change to /Page30 and /Page31 - but for some reason they are not being correctly routed.  Any help appreciated.  FWIW, I'm using Angular CLI with Web Pack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So is it working with `{ path: '', component: Page30Component }`? If so, I imagine it's because Page30 is setup as the parent route that points to the module, and within the child roots the child route is set to Page30. So `www.asdf.com/Page30/Page30` and `www.asdf.com/Page31/Page30` would be equivalent.

So the app routes would be:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: Page1Component },                          // <-- default page
  { path: 'Page1', component: Page1Component },
  { path: 'Page2', component: Page2Component },
  { path: 'Page3', component: Page3Component },
  { path: 'Lazy', loadChildren: './+lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' },

  // { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }           // <-- route not found
];
```

and the child routes could be:

```
const routes: Routes = [    
  {path: 'Page30', component: Page30Component},
  {path: 'Page31', component: Page31Component}    
];
```

which you would access via `www.asdf.com/Lazy/Page30` and `www.asdf.com/Lazy/Page31`

Comment: Perfecto.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same thing and I have found a solution.

In app.module routing you can do something like

```
{
 path: '',
 component: UserLayoutComponent,
 children: [
 {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
 {
  path: '',
  loadChildren:'app/user/user/user.module#UserModule'
 }
 ]
 }
```

Now the UserModule is lazy loaded

and in User Module routing can go like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
 { path: 'edit', component: EditProfileComponent} 
];
```

likewise profile and edit will work like : localhost:8080/profile and localhost:8080/edit

To check if the module is actually lazy loading put some console.log() inside module's constructor.

Hope this helps, thanks